# Cakephp3: Return image content from controller

Tags: php, image, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an application made in cakephp3 and I want to load the images directly from the controller, with a url like user/photo/{id}.

```
  public function foto($id)
{
  $usuario = $this->Usuario->get($id);
  $foto = $usuario['foto'];
  if (strpos($foto, "base64")===false) {
      $content = file_get_contents($foto,FILE_BINARY);
    $format=  getimagesize($foto);
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type($format['mime']);

    $this->response->body($content);
  }
  else{
    $array = explode(":",$foto);
    $type = explode(";",$array[1])[0];
    $type = explode("/",$type)[1];

    $data = explode( ',', $foto );

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type($type);
    $source = ( base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $foto)));
    $this->response->body($source);
  }
  //
  return $this->response;

}
```

Today, I have two cases of uploads: one by external url, and the other by base64 encoded image
First case:

```
  $content = file_get_contents($foto,FILE_BINARY);
    $format=  getimagesize($foto);
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type($format['mime']);

    $this->response->body($content);
```

Second Case:

```
$array = explode(":",$foto);
    $type = explode(";",$array[1])[0];
    $type = explode("/",$type)[1];

    $data = explode( ',', $foto );

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type($type);
    $source = ( base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $foto)));
    $this->response->body($source);
```

The problem is that none of them works. Both return a empty image. How do I get the images to load correctly?

Comment: Why do you read file contents into an array? And why do you then serialize it? btw, PHPs [**stream wrappers**](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) support `data:` out of the box. That being said, do some debugging, check what values you are actually working with and sending, check the server response details in your browsers network console, ...

Comment: I was reading with file_get_contents in binary mode. And I was able to save the file. But when  i tried to use the content as body in cake, it didnt work. And data can solve my problem with base64encoded files, but not external url.

Answer (score 0):

you forgotten it:

[See section sending files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files)

Cause you use cakephp 3.x you need:

```
$response = $this->response->withFile('FILE_SOURCE_PATH')
return $response;
```

assign that you need to the response and return it.
you error is don't assign the response object.

Comment: is the same to the body, status, type or file you need return.

Comment: This is to cakephp 3.4. Prior to 3.4 you have to use this way; 

// Prior to 3.4.0
$file = $this->Attachments->getFile($id);
$this->response->file($file['path']);
// Return the response to prevent controller from trying to render
// a view.
return $this->response;